# Pandas to_csv not executing in final iteration of for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am outputting items from a dataframe to a csv. The data, however, is too long for some older downstream applications, so I have the csv add line breaks every X items so that individual rows in the output aren't too long.

Example:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K  #this is actually a column in the input, rendered horizontal for space
```

Becomes in the file (X=3) -

```
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
J,K
```

Where the uneven final row is intended, as that case will be fairly common.

Actual Code fragment:

```
data = pd.read_csv(infilename, header=None)
size=50
col=0
indexes = np.arange(0,len(data),size) #have to use numpy since range is now an immutable type in python 3
indexes = np.append(indexes,[len(data)]) #add the uneven final index
for i in range(len(indexes)-1):
    holder = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[indexes[i]:indexes[i+1],col]).T
    holder.to_csv(outfilename, index=False, header=False)
```

The only weirdness is that, despite not throwing any errors, the final loop (with the uneven final index) does not write to the file, even though the information is assigned to holder perfectly. Since no errors are thrown, I cannot figure out why the final information is not being written. Does anyone know what could be causing just the final write command to fail?

EDIT:

OK, I just tried hardcoding the paths and removing all tkinter. Now, it writes the data perfectly BUT it no longer shows the variable mode behavior; it repeatedly overwrites the single line of data, but it writes the last set successfully. The example below includes a modified for loop to account for this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

infilename = 'C:\\Users\\...infile.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(infilename, header=None) #usecols=[0], only get 1st column, specify no header
outfilename = 'C:\\Users\\...test.txt'

size=50 #number of items per line
col=0
indexes = np.arange(0,len(data),size)#have to use numpy since range is now an immutable type in python 3
indexes = np.append(indexes,[len(data)]) #add the uneven final index
for i in range(len(indexes)-1):
    holder = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[indexes[i]:indexes[i+1],col]).T
    if i ==0:
        holder.to_csv(outfilename, index=False, header=False)
    else:
        holder.to_csv(outfilename, index=False, header=False, mode='a')
```

This is still problematic since I need the end user to be able to use this without tech literacy.

Comment: You could use list(range(...)) if you want to work with a list. Obviously numpy also works! Are you sure it is trying all the rows? Shouldn't it be "for i in range(len(indexes)):" (without the -1)?

Comment: Are you sure you not just overwriting the same CSV file? (we don't know where you define the `outfilename`, if inside the loop or not)

Comment: Yes, I checked the indexing. It does go through the final loop, and the final loop does put the proper data into holder. It just then fails to write it to the file. removing the `-1` causes it to run over the end of the dataframe (due to the `indexes[i+1]`).

Comment: It all writes into the same CSV file line by line. I was worried about that too, and I think it's actually an inconsistency in how the `to_csv` function works. Since I didn't set the mode param, it should default to `w` behavior, but it seems to somehow be holding state since it will overwrite the file when the new write starts (I was expecting to have to put an `if` in to change modes, but I tested it first without it and it turned out to work). This could have something to do with the failure to write in the last iteration.

Comment: Found some kind of interaction between tkinter and Pandas that partially explains the issue (Bug report submitted:https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14628)